# SQL trigger update another table column after insert

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert, average

I have a table named `Ratings` with columns `User_No`, `Recipe_No`, and `Rating`

After insert, I would like to update the `Avg_Rating` column on another table named `Recipes`.

I'm new to SQL syntax, but this is bascally what I'm trying to do

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Update_Avg` AFTER INSERT ON `Ratings`
FOR EACH ROW 
SELECT @recipeNo = Recipe_No FROM INSERTED;

SELECT @avg = AVG(Rating) FROM databs.Ratings WHERE
`Recipe_No` = @recipeNo;

INSERT INTO databs.Recipes (`Avg_Rating`) VALUES (@avg)
WHERE `Recipe_No` = @recipeNo;
```

Comment: what db server are you using?

Comment: @shibormot I am using MySQL. I already realize there are some major errors in my syntax but basically I need to find the AVG() of a column from table1 and insert it into a column on table2, and implement this on a trigger after insert on table1.